# Magento Upgrade Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

Upgrade from Magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1

Some customization has been made, I have modify some for the **.phtml files** , e.g view.phtml, text.phtml ( about product custom options), and some css files as well.

Since they are not the core files, i wonder if the update will restore these files to original after the update?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you dont have backup ?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did backup but thinking if it is better to do the update or install allover again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. If you did not modified the core files the new version will not overwrite your changes. If you modified PHTMLs from the app/design/frontend/base or app/design/frontend/default directories the case is different since those are indeed core files and the upgrade will overwrite the files and your changes.

Answer (score 1):

In general it should be fine. However, if you're using a theme which gets updated at the same time as your upgrade it may overwrite those files (happens if you don't pay attention to what you're updating). Hence it's recommended to copy all of a theme's files to a new folder or a new namespace. You should definitely make a backup before doing any upgrade in any case, I recommend also making a tarball of the files (instead of relying solely on magento's backup functionality).